# CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent and DST

Tags: objective-c, time, timezone, utc, dst

I'm developing an app for iPhone that uploads pictures to a webserver. These pictures have the time of when they were taken in the filename. Since they can be taken from anywhere in the World, I have to keep attention to timezones and DST. I thought I can use CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent, that shouldn't be localized ([NSDate date] returns the localized version of time, with or without "AM", "PM", "p.m." or any other variant... for example it returns Arabian characters, if your phone is set in arabic language!).

So, can you suggest me a function to convert CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent to a "MySQL like" date, something like "2011-11-03 14:12:10"?

My second question is: what about timezones and daylight saving? CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent always returns an UTC date, no matter how the iPhone timezone is set? Is it always DST-free?

Of course I know that the local iPhone date/time could be wrong, but milliseconds-precision is not important for my application :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What on earth do you mean by

> ([NSDate date] returns the localized version of time, with or without "AM", "PM", "p.m." or any other variant... for example it returns Arabian characters, if your phone is set in arabic language!).

`[NSDate date]` returns an `NSDate*` object. I'm assuming what you really mean is the output of `-[NSDate description]` returns a string localized in the user's current locale, but then the question is, why are you depending on the output of `-[NSDate date]`? If you need to format a date a certain way, you should use an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You're right, I think the problem of "strange" characters derives from NSDateFormatter. My current code is:

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *mysql_current_time = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

... that returns a date with arabian characters, if the iPhone is set to arabic, and returns scrabled strings if the user's locale includes AM/PM/A.M./P.M. variants or in general if it's not in 24h format.

Comment: @flip79: You probably want to look at the `-[NSDateFormatter setLocale:]` method.

Answer (score 0):

`CFAbsoluteTime` represents a moment in time, independent of time zones or localization settings. If you want to format a date (i.e. an `NSDate` object) you should look at `NSDateFormatter`, which lets you specify the exact format and localization (if any) of the output string. (If you need to work at the Core Foundation level, `CFDateFormatter` does the same thing.)